# Is it possible to enable integrated graphics on a laptop?

Tags: laptop, integrated-graphics

sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question. Since a few days my laptop is BSODing with error atikmpag.sys (after showing a garbled screen when booting) if I install amd graphics drivers. If however I uninstall the amd driver, it boots up fine. Is it possible to enable the integrated graphics that is present in the cpu (i5 3230m)? Looks like the gpu needs reflow, but that is last resort option, so it would be fine with integrated graphics (if possible). The only problem I have without gpu installed is that I can't change the screen brightness(always full brightness). Also I went to a laptop repair shop, the person says he'll remove the gpu from mobo and enable integrated graphics, but I don't trust him as I'm sure the gpu is fine.

One more question I have is that why my computer display works fine without gpu driver installed? Could it be integrated graphics powering it?

Also on my laptop support page, an integrated graphics driver software (intel hd graphics) is also available. So is it possible?

OR

If it is not possible, is there a way to enable brightness change.

Note: Tried to install different versions of amd drivers with same result, used DDU to wipe and re-install drivers, tried some fixes found on google, nothing works!! Warrantly period is over :(

The only reason I'm asking this question is because that person (laptop repair shop) said he'll do it (enable integrated graphics)

My laptop model: Sony Vaio SVE15137cn
cpu: i5-3230m
gpu: AMD Radeon HD7650m
OS: Windows 10 (anniversary update installed)
BIOS version: R0180D5

Answer (score 0):

Without AMD drivers installed the laptop should automatically fall back to integrated graphics. And you should install those Intel HD Graphics drivers, because without them the integrated graphics run in "standard vga mode", which is very limited.
Installing the Intel drivers could even give you the screen-brightness controls back, although that is not guaranteed. Depends from laptop-model to laptop-model on exactly how the brightness-control is build in to the laptop.

In some laptops there is a Bios option to set "integrated graphics" to on/off/auto. If you have this option best set it to ON to make sure it is always on.

Please be advised: If indeed re-flow is your problem it can get gradually worse to the point the laptop becomes totally unusable. It wouldn't hurt to start saving money for a new laptop...

Comment: Hey Tonny appreciate the suggestion, but there is no option in bios to enable integrated graphics. Intel graphics drivers also won't install(ones from Intel website). But the one from Sony support will install but won't activate(because it was provided for Windows 8). I'll try different versions of Intel graphics. I guess integrated graphics is there, biggest clue that Sony provided integrated graphics driver for my laptop (for windows 8 only though ) .